# Grub install failing on Hardware RAID with LVM

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, lvm, hardware-raid, grub

I have a SuperMicro box with an Areca RAID controller installed. The RAID controller is configured for RAID 6 + Hot Spare. I am attempting to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I set up LVM with separate partitions for /, /var, swap, and /data. While progressing through the installer, I get repeated failures at the Grub install step: "Unable to install grub /dev/sda" -- attempting to manually specify the location where Grub should be installed (presumably /dev/mapper/vg0-root) yields a similar result.

LVM Configuration:
[image]
[image]

The installation step that triggers the failure:
[image]

Error:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Crap. I've seen this very error, but the documentation for how I fixed it is at a workplace I no longer work for. It involved going into text mode to reorder some things in grub and THEN applying, but that's all I got.

Comment: Do you have a /boot partition ( outside of lvm of course ) ?

Comment: No I do not. Should I try placing /boot outside of LVM?

Comment: 52TB in a single RAID6 volume? I hope you never need to rebuild your RAID.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by destroying the LVM and placing a small 2MB grub-bios partition at the beginning of /dev/sda. I presume, but cannot confirm, that that wasn't ample space for grub to install. From what I have read, GRUB has become so bloated it now extends beyond the bounds of sector 0. I am not sure if anyone might be able to confirm my theory.

Comment: Nope, 2MB is the normal and recommended size for a BIOS boot partition on a GPT formatted disk. The size has nothing to do with grub.

Comment: @MichaelHampton so if I understand you correctly you are saying that because this is not a GPT formatted disk that it was not a matter of space? Do you have any thoughts as to what might have resolved my issue? I am glad the issue is resolved but would prefer to understand why this actually seemed to resolve the issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, it _is_ a GPT formatted disk. You could not have created a 52 TB partition otherwise.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I apologize, so are you saying it was simply the addition of the 2MB grub-bios partition at the beginning of the disk that was requisite for the grub install - but that it was not a matter of size itself.